# How to generate URL for the action with attribute routing in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("Users/about")]
    [Route("Users/WhoareWe")]
    [Route("Users/OurTeam")]
    [Route("Users/aboutCompany")]
    public ActionResult GotoAbout()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I have many routes defined for action `GotoAbout()`.

How to create route URL in razor page programmatically when generate URL for action like `home/users/about` ?

Comment: Give the route a name and reference route directly by name.

Comment: how to do it....can you give me a small example code if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5 - Route Names](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/#route-names)

You can specify a name for a route, in order to easily allow URI generation for it.

For example, for the following route:

```
[RoutePrefix("Home")]
public class HomeController : Controller {
    [Route("Users/about", Name = "Users_About")]
    [Route("Users/WhoareWe")]
    [Route("Users/OurTeam")]
    [Route("Users/aboutCompany")]
    public ActionResult GotoAbout() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

you could generate a link using `Url.RouteUrl`:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Users_About")">About</a>
```

which would resolve to

```
<a href="home/users/about">About</a>
```

Comment: can i generate route url like this way `@Html.RouteLink(Model.PostTitle, " ArticlesPost ", new { category = Model.postCategory.Category, url = Model.PostUrl }, new { @class = "title" })`   code taken from http://www.dotnet-tutorial.com/articles/mvc/getting-started-with-custom-routing-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: What would be the alternative for ASP.NET 6.0 where RoutePrefix doesn't exist?

Comment: @MendiSterenfeld it has been replaced with just `Route` attribute. Reference: [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Comment: @Nkosi took me a few hours to figure it out, still having problems with combining the Prefix with the Method in the cshtml. Check out my last question. thank you