# What is the Name property on Http verbs attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.httpmethodattribute.name?view=aspnetcore-3.0) for this property, nothing is said, so what exactly does this property do?

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.httpmethodattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.0#properties) is also missing some description of what it does.

Comment: the entire routing docs for ASP.NET Core are pretty bad, they don't explain how to properly route queries, which makes it so confusing for me to build an API with multiple parameters for requests.

Comment: If you look at the source (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Routing/HttpMethodAttribute.cs) you'll see that the property is inherited from the IRouteTemplateProvider interface, where it's properly documented: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Routing/IRouteTemplateProvider.cs

Comment: So it just specifies the action name? does that mean that something like this `[HttpGet("{requestedId}&{requestorId}", Name = "GetById")]` would path to `api/Controller/GetById?{requestedId}&{requestorId}`? @KevinGosse

Comment: No, it's just when you need to refer to the route, for instance to generate a link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620195/869621

Comment: Ohh so you're saying that it doesn't even have to do with specific routing, it's just for the rest of the code to have a name for that specific route?

Comment: @tempacc555 the docs are pretty clear what they are for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#route-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core :](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#route-name)

> ### Route Name
>
> The following code defines a route name of `Products_List`:

```
public class ProductsApiController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet("/products/{id}", Name = "Products_List")]
   public IActionResult GetProduct(int id) { ... }
}
```

> Route names can be used to generate a URL based on a specific route. Route names have no impact on the URL matching behavior of routing and are only used for URL generation. Route names must be unique application-wide.

#### Reference [Generating URLs by route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?#generating-urls-by-route)